# SQL Server return table to MS Access via stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access, stored-procedures, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to return a table back to MS Access that has 50+ columns and the rows can vary from 0 to 5000. For each case there can be multiple records and vehicle type.

I can execute the stored procedure and it works fine. I'm having trouble getting the data to return back to MS Access.

Stored procedure code:

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[pJDB_Export] 
    (@dteFrom int, 
     @dteTo int,
     @Veh nvarchar(80))
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @stWhere VARCHAR(200)

    SELECT DISTINCT [Case] 
    INTO #tmp 
    FROM data 
    WHERE [VEHICLE TYPE] = @Veh 
      AND (CY BETWEEN @dteFrom AND @dteTo)

    SELECT DISTINCT * 
    FROM dbo.vdata_Export_V3_3_2 v
    INNER JOIN #tmp t ON v.[CASE] = t.[CASE]
```

MS Access code:

```vb
Function Exec_pJDB_export(sqlConn as string)
    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim cmd As ADODB.Command

    Dim iFrom, iTo As Integer
    Dim stv As String
    iFrom = 1999
    iTo = 2002
    stv = "1 TO 2 TON TRUCKS (COMMERCIAL)"
    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection

    conn.Open "DSN=Cars"
    conn.ConnectionString = sqlConn
    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
    cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
    cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    cmd.CommandText = "pJDB_export"

    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@dteFrom", adInteger, adParamInput, , iFrom)
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@dteTo", adInteger, adParamInput, , iTo)
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@vehicle", adVarChar, adParamInput, 80, stv)

    cmd.Execute
    conn.Close

End Function
```

Comment: What trouble are you having?  Is the code returning an error message or are you unsure how to access the records?  If the latter, you'll need an [ADO recordset](https://www.w3schools.com/asp/ado_ref_recordset.asp).

Comment: Nothing is being returned and no error messages.   Not sure how to access the records via ADO

Comment: Check out ExecuteReader()
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereader(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Sorry @pmbAustin, that's ADO.Net.  This is *classic* ADO, which does not support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [execute method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/execute-method-ado-connection) returns a [recordset object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/recordset-object-ado).  It is this object that contains your records.  Here is example:

```
Function Exec_pJDB_export(sqlConn As String)
    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset               ' ADO recordset object, for accessing records.

    Dim iFrom, iTo As Integer
    Dim stv As String
    iFrom = 1999
    iTo = 2002
    stv = "1 TO 2 TON TRUCKS (COMMERCIAL)"
    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection

    conn.Open "DSN=Cars"
    conn.ConnectionString = sqlConn
    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
    cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
    cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    cmd.CommandText = "pJDB_export"

    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@dteFrom", adInteger, adParamInput, , iFrom)
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@dteTo", adInteger, adParamInput, , iTo)
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@vehicle", adVarChar, adParamInput, 80, stv)

    ' This line has changed.
    Set rs = cmd.Execute()


    ' Loops over the records.
    Do Until rs.EOF

        ' Display the contents of column one to the user.
        MsgBox rs.Fields(0).Value

        rs.MoveNext
    Loop



    rs.Close
    conn.Close
End Function
```

Quick overview:

1. [EOF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/bof-eof-properties-ado) stands for *End of File*.  It is true when you have viewed all records.
2. Don't forget to call [MoveNext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/movefirst-movelast-movenext-and-moveprevious-methods-ado), or the do loop will continue forever!

The line `rs.Fields(0).Value` can be changed to `rs.Fields("YourFieldName").Value`, if you prefer.  I find it easier to refer to fields by name, rather than position.

Comment: that works.  One final question.  Exporting it to excel or access table.  One columns have length < 500 and another has 10,000+ characters.

Comment: that works.  One final question.  I prefer exporting the data to a table if must I can dump it to excel.  One columns have length < 500 chars and another has 10,000+ chars.    What is the best way to export the data?   

I prefer not having to scroll thru the recordset by columns and rows.

Thanks

Comment: Although VBA/ADO can do this, there are easier methods. [Pass through queries](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/303968/how-to-create-an-sql-pass-through-query-in-access) can display your SP as a table. As a added bonus they are code free.